# pip install from local directory doesnt add [build-system] dependencies

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml, setuptools-scm

In our project ([Locust](https://github.com/locustio/locust/)) we use `setuptools_scm` for versioning, so it is needed for all installations from local directory.

We used to have this specified in setup.py:

```
setup(
    setup_requires=["setuptools_scm>=6.2"],
    ...
)
```

But we have upgraded to use `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools_scm>=6.2", ...]
```

This works nicely in most cases, **but it does not install setuptools_scm if someone does** `pip install -e .` (it doesnt work for `pip install .` either but that is less important)

With no `setuptools_scm` installed the local version becomes 0.0.0:

```
~/git/locust pip install -e .
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
...
  Running setup.py develop for locust
Successfully installed locust-0.0.0
```

... and that makes me very sad.

What is the appropriate way make pip install `setuptools_scm` when installing from source?

I could of course add it as a regular dependency in setup.cfg, but that would make thousands of users download `setuptools_scm` even when it is not needed (when installing from PyPi)

Comment: Not sure it is supported yet. PEP 660 support in setuptools is very, very new. Maybe ask in [this discussion here](https://discuss.python.org/t/help-testing-pep-660-support-in-setuptools/16904), or on the ticket trackers of [_`setuptools`_](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues) or [_`setuptools_scm`_](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues). -- I wonder if [this ticket here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3501) might be related.

Comment: Some seem to say that it worked for their use case: https://discuss.python.org/t/help-testing-pep-660-support-in-setuptools/16904/19 and https://discuss.python.org/t/help-testing-pep-660-support-in-setuptools/16904/29